# About characters and Unicode Relationship in Java

Tags: java, unicode, cryptography

**Encryption logic:**

- Gets an input text.
- The characters of the entered text will be one by
  one.
- The characters get their Unicode equivalent as Integer. And adds
  the length (length ()) of the text entered to this value.

> int uniCode=input.charAt(i)+input.length();

**Decryption logic:**

- Separates the integer password into 3 digits (Latin).
- Subtracts the length of the keyword (input.length) from the separated
  3-digit Integer expression.
- Convert the result to the corresponding character in Unicode.

> deCryp=(char)(Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i, i+3))-input.length());

This encryption work, which works in frequently used Latin characters, can make a 3-digit Unicode translation in the binary system. Can we write this in a way that we can read the binary equivalent (4-5 digits) without reading the numbers?

I performed an encryption and decryption study, my classes are as follows:

**Main Class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        Crip crip=new Crip();
        System.out.println("Enter the your key words = ");
        String key= input.nextLine();
        
        crip.enCryption(key);
        crip.showInfos();
        crip.deCryption(key);
    }

}
```

**Cryption Class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Crip {
    private ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
    private String Password="";
    
    
    public void enCryption(String input) {
        input=input.toLowerCase();
        for (int i=0;i<input.length();i++) {
            if(input.substring(i)!=null) {
                int uniCode=input.charAt(i)+input.length();
                list.add(uniCode);
            }
            else {
                list.add(0);
            }
        }
        for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
            Password+=list.get(i);
            if(i+1!=list.size()) {
                Password+="-";
            }
            
        }
    }

    public void deCryption(String input) {
        String str = Password.split(" ")[0];
        str=str.replace("-","");
        char deCryp;
        System.out.print("deCryption  : ");
            for (int i=0;i<str.length();i=i+3) {
                deCryp=(char)(Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i, i+3))-input.length());
                System.out.print(deCryp);
            }
    }

    public void showInfos() {
        System.out.println("enCryption  : "+Password);
    }

    
    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        Password = password;
    }

}
```

Comment: Aside: `input.substring(i)` is never null.

Comment: I don't think you can assume there are always 3 characters in the number. For example, `0` (49) in a string of length less than 51 would be just two characters. And unicode codepoints mostly have values greater than 999. You don't really need to assume a fixed length, you can just look for the next `-` with `indexOf`.

Comment: I understand what you said, thanks. I guess if I add a space character and read instead of deleting the "-" character in the application, it will print every Unicode expression.